# Kibana Elasticsearch - Index Missing

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have kibana connected to elastic search, however when doing a search I see in the web console: `"IndexMissingException[[INDEX_MISSING] missing]"`

The url is literally going for :9200/INDEX_MISSING/_mapping

Where can I specify the Index?

Comment: Did you by any luck tried google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the Index tab in Kibana's Dashboard Settings page and set your Timestamping and Index Pattern settings.

For example, you could choose daily timestamping with an index pattern of:

```
[logstash-]YYYY.MM.DD
```

Remember to save your dashboard after making these changes.